# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I've received the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

After running the code bellow:

```
train=data[:training_data_len]
valid=data[training_data_len:]
valid['Predictions']=predictions
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Close Price USD',fontsize=20)
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Close','Predictions']])
plt.legend(['Train', 'Val', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show
```

Before the ''training_data_len'' was written as:

```
data_close=df.filter(['Close'])
dataset=data_close.values 
training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * 0.8) 
training_data_len
```

Being equal to 202.

Comment: Please post the *full* error trace (as text), and *remove* any code that may come after the error (it is never executed, hence irrelevant).

Comment: What is `predictions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is not a list, but a dataframe (the same type as `df`). You need to change

```
train = data[:training_data_len]
```

to

```
train = data['Close'][:training_data_len]
```

And the same for `valid`

Comment: Thank you!! it helped me in see in where was the mistake. I called data, on the top of my code, as df. So, I wrote:

`train = df.filter(['Close'])[:training_data_len]
valid = df.filter(['Close'])[training_data_len:] `